# PHP connection to MS SQL. Works on workstations but not on 2 servers

Tags: php

Ok. If I had hair, it would all be on the floor at this point. I have the same files on a laptop and my work machine and works with no problems at all (of course). I put it on two other machines two days ago and get the errors below. I have been researching and fighting since then.

I have tested odbc and pdo_odbc but no luck there either.

I'm sure it's something stupid but any help would be appreciated.

Prereqs:

- PHP 7.2.5,
- MS SQL 2008 R2,
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64 bit

:

```
<?php

$serverName = "Agency"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Dashboard_DB", "UID"=>"uname", "PWD"=>"pword");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>

?>
```

I get this:

```
Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x86: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x86: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

I've tried the files in the link in the result but still the same results.

Here is the PHP.ini extension section

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64
;extension=php_pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Comment: If you use sqlsrv_errors() http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php what errors are returned?

Comment: Exact same return as above.

Comment: On the two computers where it doesn't work have you checked that the database user exists, is spelt (including the right case) as it is on the server and that the user has the required permissions?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I did. We actually have another one of our programs written in C# that connects to our other dbs. Used the same username and password. Even tested it with our sa account. Same results

Comment: What versions of PHP,  MS SQL server and Windows Server are you running on the laptop?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Actually have it on 4 laptops and 1 workstation. They are running Windows 10 (for sales) and vary from SQL 2008 R2 up to 2017. All have PHP 7.2.5.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's either a permissions problem with Windows (Windows 10 not allowing something somewhere to run) or something required perhaps doesn't exist in Windows 10

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I apologize. It's working on all of the laptops and workstations. It's not working on the Windows server. From the research I've been doing it looks like it's the version of the ODBC driver on the server. I may be completely off base

Comment: Did this start happening around the time you upgraded them all to use PHP 7.2.5? What PHP version was you using before?

Comment: I believe I figured it out. I uninstalled the ODBC drivers and reinstalled the sqlsrv40 ODBC driver. At least I can see the CONCATs failing now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in  your server, you checked if the folder extensions for PHP  have the correct file .dll?

drivers may also need [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)  or [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server® - Windows + Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420) to work

if  you not have the .dll, you can download and install (the installer just extract  .dll's in target folder) [Microsoft Drivers 5.2 for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56729)  to folder "PHP/ext"

here [System Requirements for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017) you will see the appropriated driver

Comment: Triple checked them all. Exact the same files. Transferred the new drivers anyway. Same results.

Comment: Uninstalled the ODBC drivers. Reinstalled the version 11 and rebooted.
Thanks for the help.